# How to javascript match exactly 7 numbers from different urls

Tags: javascript, regex, match, bookmarklet

I have URL addresses like

- http://www.gg.omg/list/name/25/1343689
- http://www.gg.omg/omg/20/5543189
- http://www.gg.omg/23/something/9303033
- http://www.gg.omg/whatever/4303013/maybe

My javascript bookmarklet looks something like below.

```
javascript:(function(){javascript:var location_pathname = document.location.href;var ggId = location_pathname.match(/^[0-9]{7}$/)[1]; window.open('http://localhost/script.php?id='+ggId, '_blank')})()
```

How to match those 7 numbers from each urls? Above is my script but it does not work. If I match example with `"/\/something\/(.*)/"` code works and opens new tab http://localhost/script.php?id=9303033 but it works only in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are exactly 7 digits after slash (/) and another slash or EOL then correct RegEx is

```
var re = /\/(\d{7})\/?|$/; //note (\d{7}) This is what will be captured
//tests
'http://www.gg.omg/whatever/4303013'.match(re)[1]; //4303013
'http://www.gg.omg/whatever/4303013/maybe'.match(re)[1]; //4303013
'http://www.gg.omg/whatever/430301'.match(re)[1]; //undefined
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much, now I can sleep well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ^ at the start of the regex, and the $ at the end, to match at any places of the url.

```
location_pathname.match(/([0-9]{7})/)[1];
```

Comment: I tried it already but then browser opens this :S
http://localhost/script.php?id=undefined

Comment: @sukkis and this? location_pathname.match(/\d{7}/)[1];

Comment: Yep. Still same reaction? Is there something else broken even /\/something\/(.*)/ as said is working?

Comment: @sukkis try this then and see if it an array index issue ?
location_pathname.match(/\d+/)[1]
and this location_pathname.match(/\d+/)

Comment: @AlexKudryashev right! Missed that, don't know how :)